# Laravel Uploading a photo

Tags: laravel-5

Hi i am trying to upload a photo but i do not get the filename of the photo in my database..The photo successfully uploads to my folder.i have this in my controller

```
public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) 
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save( public_path('uploads/posts/' .$filename));


        Auth::user()->posts()->create([
            'body'       => $request->body,
            'username' => Auth::user()->name,
            'photo' => $filename,


        ]); 
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        return view('home', ['post' => $posts]);
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am missing

Comment: make sure column 'photo' is varchar or correct type

Comment: got it thanks grasper